# Enable PSQL hstore extension in Django test db during CI

Tags: django, postgresql, testing, hstore

## **Context**

Some steps of my Continuos Integration procedure are:

- start Postgres docker container
- run Django tests

When `manage.py test --noinput` command is runned it:

- creates a new `test_xxx` database (drop if exists)
- runs the founded migrations against it
- runs the founded set of tests

Into the tests that need to fetch data from the database are configured a set of fixtures that will be loaded automatically in the `test_xxx` db.

## **Problem**

Some migrations need the Postgres `hstore` extension, in fact i'm getting this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "hstore" does not exist

## **Question**

How can i enable the hstore extension?

In development and other envs it was set up with `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;` but here can't be manually set.

Is possible to define a "migration zero" with the hstore creation? Anyway i don't like this approach.

I've found that it should be theorically possible to listen to the `pre_migrate` signal, and it will be the sweet spot, but before make things more complex i'd like to search for an easier, more direct solution.

EDIT: in this particular case i must use Django 1.8, [since 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.11/#database-backends) is possible to define a template from which create the test db, so is possible to define a template with the hstore and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The final workaround until the Django update is:

- when start the Postgre container add an `init.sql` file with the `test_xxx` database creation and `hstore` extension
- when launching the django tests, instead of using the `--noinput` flag, use the `--keepdb` one so the db isn't recreated